# Alternative to GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: winapi

I need to detect if various combinations of the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, & <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys are pressed at program startup time. This has to happen BEFORE any window is opened.

I know all about **GetAsyncKeyState** but this function doesn't work if your program is not the foreground task in Windows, and when a program is first launched, it's not the foreground task until a window is opened.

Program is WIN32/C++/MFC/32-bit. Any ideas?

---

*Additional Info Added:*  This is running on 64-bit Win8.  Also, while I only mentioned **GetAsyncKeyState**, I had also tried **GetKeyState** but the results didn't really reflect the **CURRENT** status and never did work for <kbd>Alt</kbd> at all.

Here's a code example taken from my app class **InitInstance** method (that's essentially the main() for an MFC app), before the main window is opened.

```
#define USE_GETASYNCKEYSTATE (1)

// Following two lines are added for testing so there's a
// specific time to make sure keys are pressed
AfxMessageBox("Press keys after dismissing this message");
Sleep(2000);

#if USE_GETASYNCKEYSTATE
    short altKeyStatus = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU) & 0x8000;
    short shiftKeyStatus = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000;
    short controlKeyStatus = (short)GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000;
#else
    char kbBuf[256];
    GetKeyboardState( (PBYTE)kbBuf );
    short altKeyStatus = (short)kbBuf[VK_MENU];
    short shiftKeyStatus = (short)kbBuf[VK_SHIFT];
    short controlKeyStatus = (short)kbBuf[VK_CONTROL];
#endif

CString msg;
msg.Format("ALT: %d, SHIFT: %d, CTRL: %d", 
                altKeyStatus, shiftKeyStatus, controlKeyStatus );
AfxMessageBox(msg);
```

When it runs using **GetAsyncKeyState**, all three variables are returning ZERO at all times.

When I run the **GetKeyboardState** block, I sometimes get results indicating that <kbd>Shift</kbd> and/or <kbd>Control</kbd> have been pressed.  That is, pressed sometime recently, but not necessarily matching the *current* status, and it is never returning anything but zero for <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Note that the first two lines with **Sleep** can be removed without changing the results at all.  I added them so I could be sure that the keypress occurred while the program was actually running.

Answer (score 2):

No, you got that backwards.  It is `GetKeyState()` that won't work, `GetAsyncKeyState()` is fine.  You should normally use `GetKeyState()` since it returns the buffered state of the keyboard.  Important because keyboard messages are buffered in the message queue.  But that can't work when your program doesn't have the focus or hasn't created the message queue yet.  The latter is your case.

Pick your magic keys carefully, they tend to get in the way of clicking a desktop shortcut.  I found the Scroll Lock key useful in this kind of case.  Isn't used for much of anything, it typically even has a light and it latches state so can be turned on without panicking the keyboard.

Comment: Link to MSDN entry for GetAsyncKeyState: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The return value is zero for the following cases: "The foreground thread belongs to another process and the desktop does not allow the hook or the journal record.", that should be your problem. For the record, I've used `GetAsyncKeyState` successfully in the past.

Comment: Rodrigo, I am well aware of that.  It's part of my original question.  Why it's not working isn't a mystery... I just need an alternative.

Comment: Hans, using Scroll Lock is a clever idea but it won't work in this case for several reasons.  First, the SHIFT/ALT/CTRL detection is to initiate special case/diagnostic functions that regular users won't even know about, and who is to say they won't have it on for some reason? Second, it's only one key and I need several combinations.  Third, it's missing from many keyboards.

Comment: I've used it to bring up a dialog with startup options, avoids having to give meaning to multiple keys.  I've never seen a keyboard without it.  Your test code is tricky because you call MessageBox, it has side-effects that includes creating a message queue so it *looks* like GetKeyboardState() works.  No theory about getting a 0.  The boilerplate usage is `bool shiftDown = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0;`  You want an alternative, there isn't any.  GetAsyncKeyState() has always worked fine for me, it still does when I try it on Win8.  Good luck with it.

Comment: Laptops don't always have scroll lock. In particular, Mac laptops do not, and users with MacBook Pro laptops running Windows under Boot Camp or in a virtual machine represent a significant portion of my target user base.

The MessageBox and Sleep calls have been commented out or deleted most of the time I've been dealing with this, but even when active I've seen no change in behavior.

You say GetAsyncKeyState works for for you... I've used it myself in other situations without problems, but are you ever using it at program initialization without any window open yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your import of that function is correct because you're casting the result of it to `short` which should be `short` already. I had also a problem with `GetAsyncKeyState` and I solved it by correcting the import:

```
// C#
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int virtualKey);
```

For a strange reason it worked only **sometimes** when I had `int` as result.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your response, but this is C++ code, not C#, so there is no import declaration like this. The function prototype is included in one of the basic Windows header files. And the cast to short is some old grunge but it's optimized into nothingness... makes no difference in the resulting code at all.

Comment: Like explained I had a problem with GetAsyncKeyState and solved it. If you still have your problem with it you might try a different approach by importing the function on your own or whatever.